# Angularjs: How to merge multiple html files into single html file and load single html file from js file

Tags: angularjs

I merged all html files into single html file and I included them inside app.js file here its loading that single file its fine and also all html files are loading. Please suggest a correct way to load only merge.html with result from test1.html, test2.html files.

See the [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3miUeU2EhS4syZhvrGey?p=preview). I posted.

Please give correct code here to load only merge.html alone but not all html files and get success results.

Answer (score 0):

Include those test1.html and test2.html as directives in app.js ,and then include those directives in merge.html. So it looks like that:

```
.directive('test1', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'test1.html',
  };
});

.directive('test2', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'test2.html',
  };
});
```

and then

```
<div test1> </div>
<div test2> </div>
```

Comment: this is fine but i am not asking this,please check i provided plunker link